# Data modeling in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I just started using Datastore, so I'm still not sure about few things.

I have the fallowing entities:

`Property:` `{ID, number, name, long, lat}`

`Address:` `{name, postCodeType}`

`City:` `{name}`

`Country:` `{name}`

`User:` `{name, username}`

So the logic behind this is that a `User` will have `multiple properties`, which means that a `property` will hold a `user key`.

As described above the `Property` has some properties, but I am not sure on how to associate the `address` `city` and `country`.

I think a solution will be to store the keys for those 3 entities in the `property entity`.

```
type Property struct {   
  ID         int64   `json:"id" datastore:"-"`
  Number     int8    `json:"number"`
  Name       string  `json:"name"`
  Long       float64 `json:"long"`
  Lat        float64 `json:"lat"`
  AddressKey *datastore.Key
  CityKey    *datastore.Key
  CountryKey *datastore.Key
  UserKey    *datastore.Key
  CreatedAt  time.Time
}
```

Is my attempt from above a good start or what do I need to do different.

Answer (score 3):

1. A list of countries rarely changes, so most programmers use an enum (or a Goland equivalent) to represent countries, instead of creating entities in the datastore. You can use ether 2-letter or 3-letter country codes, and simply save a country code as a string property within an Address entity. The enum can also return a full display name of a country based on its code.
2. I also don't see a reason to create an entity for cities, although it can be done, if really necessary. Usually, a city is saved as a string property, indexed if necessary, within an Address entity.

This means that your Address entity may look like:

```
Address: {name, street, city, country, postCode}
```

3. Going further, if each property has only one address, you may not need the Address entity at all. Which leads us to a very simple solution:

   ```
   type Property struct {   
     ID         int64   `json:"id" datastore:"-"`
     Number     int8    `json:"number"`
     Name       string  `json:"name"`
     Long       float64 `json:"long"`
     Lat        float64 `json:"lat"`
     Street     string  `json:"street"`
     City       string  `json:"city"`
     Country    string  `json:"country"`
     PostCode   string  `json:"postCode"`
     UserKey    *datastore.Key
     CreatedAt  time.Time
   }
   ```